# How to get the rows in a Datagrid that are customized in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Datagrid with n rows. And some of the rows of the datagrid have the backcolor as green. I also have a button. How can I disable the button when no rows of my Datgrid are in green.

Comment: Instead of checking back color, you can find those rows based on the criteria which made them green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the count of green colored cells

```
int greenColuredCells = (dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Where(r => r.Cells[0].Style.BackColor == Color.Green)
                    .Count();
```

and use this to hide show butten

```
btn.enable = greenColuredCells>0;
```